# Php strcmp and array

Tags: php, strcmp

I have a php array. In 5th position I have a string "A".
When I use `var_dump($myarray[4])` I have `string(38) "A"`.
I would to compare this value, so I try this code:

```
if (strcmp($myarray[4], "A") == 0) {
    echo 'OK';
}
```

but I do I never get a true condition. 
If I try to print `strcmp($myarray[4], "A")` I get **-5**
why??

Comment: Are you sure it's `"A"` and not `"A   "`?

Comment: this code should work

Comment: Actually it shouldn't. He didn't paste everything, note that var_dump says the string is 38 characters long.

Comment: sounds like you have some extra chars, try strcmp(trim($myarray[4]), "A")

Comment: Also with trim I have -5

Comment: I can try to check the encoding: how can I set a particular encoding of a string?

Comment: It would be easier for people to debug if you provide the `base64_encode($myarray[4]);` output.